# can two separate circuits use the one sensor

Tags: thermistor

I want to monitor the temperature of my washing machine. I was going to connect a raspberry pi up to the thermistor at the bottom of the drum. Would this interfere with how the washing machine measures the temperature, if both the washing machine and pi are using the sensor simultaneously?

The sensor is NTC : K276
The washing machine is Logik L712WM20

Comment: If you have the part number of the sensor and the a circuit diagram of the associated circuitry, please use the [edit] link below the question to add those details. Please also add the Pi circuitry which you are planning to attach to the sensor.

Comment: I will get the part number

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you would need to figure out how the washing machine is using the thermistor and then you might be able to use the same sensor by adapting your circuit. In the best case, it could be as simple as a voltage divider that could fairly easily be adapted, or it could be some AC scheme as is used in consumer thermometers. If the excitation is brief and periodic, it could be difficult to use it.

Also, thermistors have a wide variety of possible characteristics (not just the resistance at a reference temperature), so an unknown thermistor may not be all that easy to use accurately, even if the circuit issue is solved.

Caution- if the circuitry in the washing machine is not isolated from the mains, some very bad and potentially lethal and/or very expensive things could happen.

If you're not up for the reverse engineering  you might find it easier to just add a second sensor of known characteristics.

Comment: >you might find it easier to just add a second sensor of known characteristics, only I would need to drill a hole and make sure it is water tight, the risk of flooding would be far worse then having to replace the circuit board on the washing machine

Comment: Yes. Hence the "might".